# Edittext Numeric by code

Tags: android, android-edittext, numeric

Hello guys.

I trying set EditText to input only numbers and point (" . ") that's all. Im already using inputType.. but there numeric keyboard with "+","-" and "#" and without point/period (".") 
example for what need it  : 100.99 .. that's all. 
I found some code :

```
<EditText android:text="100.99"
android:id="@+id/EditText01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:numeric="integer|decimal" />
```

but it's in xml... i want create it by code.  Also i mean this string :

```
 android:numeric="integer|decimal"
```

Please if any one know how to set this settings by code.. reply me

Regards, Peter.

Comment: did you mean, the edit text must accept real values only ?

Comment: only numbers and point(period ".") that's all.. no input to words or symbols like "+","-" or other except period(".")

Comment: I think you have to create a new keypad for your requirements and you have to maintain it for edit text. If you don't know how to do it ask me.

Comment: @Yugandhar Babu i'm also thinking about it.. but it's take much time.Alsy if your tell me how to do it .. it will be very cool. i have only scype for quick answers :(

Comment: Please clear this thing, are you getting edittext value as **123+-345** when you pressed respective buttons ? or only **123345** ? by using the code you posted here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

**Edit :**

The suggestion i have given above was taken from Doc. but as you said it is not working properly,i can suggest you a more thing.

Add a TextWatcher to your EditText as below,after you set above input type:

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3){         

          if(arg0.length()!=0)
          {
                String s=arg0.toString();
                Character c=s.charAt(arg0.length()-1);

                if(c=='/' || c=='\\' || c=='|' || c=='"' || c==':' || c==';' || c=='?' || c=='/' || c==',' || c=='<' || c=='>' || c=='!' || c=='@' || c=='#' || c=='$' || c=='%' || c=='^' || c=='&' || c=='*' || c=='(' || c==')' || c=='_' || c=='=' || c=='+' || c=='-')
                {               
                    if(arg0.length()!=1)
                    {
                        String s1=s.substring(0,arg0.length()-1);
                        mEditText.setText(s1);
                        mEditText.setSelection(s1.length());    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mEditText.setText("");
                    }
                }
          }     
    }               
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {
    }               
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Then just use decimal,don't include number so try this: mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

Comment: please see my edit! That worked for me.also you can remove specification of input type in your xml,everytime set it by code!

Comment: xml it's only for example what i found.. i need create this without xml. That's all. also i tried your code (without xml file) and this did not work.

Comment: Tried cleaning and rebuilding project after editing your code?And please post your complete code that dynamically generates edittext and sets properties of it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6882/discussion-between-hiral-and-peter)

Comment: please join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6882/discussion-between-hiral-and-peter

Comment: hey, im there - where are u ?

Comment: @Hiral if you don't mind i have a problem with your code, the edit text receiving alphabets. I used only addTextChangedListener() method, is anything extra i have to set to EditText instance ?

Comment: join the room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6882/discussion-between-hiral-and-peter

Comment: dont forget to set input type as shown in my older answer to your edit text object before setting a text watcher to it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

// TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER: Class for numeric text. This displays the numbers/symbols keyboard.

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

// TYPE_CLASS_PHONE: Class for a phone number. This displays the phone number keypad.

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

Comment: i can input "+" and "-" .. im already tried this and it's not help me :(

Answer (score 0):

actually this works:

```
editText.setInputType((InputType.TYPE_MASK_CLASS&InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)| (InputType.TYPE_MASK_FLAGS & (InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED |InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL)));
```